# Handlebar heater

Tags: heat

I want to make Arduino controlled handlebar heater with kanthal wire. Heater should heat up handlebar(left & right grip) up to 30°C max but I'm not sure how I should calculate required length/diameter/resistance of wire. Heater will be Powered with 12V over IRFZ44N MOSFET.

Comment: If you have a pair of thermistors and PWM, there can be some leeway on the wire requirements.

Comment: Yes, plan is to control heater over PWM with feedback from thermistor.

Comment: Careful with the [IRFZ44N](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfz44n.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563b3575220b): A) \$V_{(BR)DSS} = 55v\$. Any voltage spikes above this run the risk of damaging something. Vehicle power is never "clean" and is often very spiky. B) \$V_{GS(th)} = 2-4v\$. 5v from an Arduino is not enough to fully turn this on. You'll want to switch 12v and 0v (or -12v if you have it) to the gate. To PWM this quickly, significant pulse currents are needed - use an NMOS gate driver IC. Bypass caps are your friend...

Comment: @rdtsc AIUI, slow PWM is usually acceptable for heaters. It doesn't have to be fast at all.

Comment: I won’t go over 80% duty cycle

Comment: True, but slow switching of an NMOS (with 1.47nF of gate capacitance) will cause it to heat up and waste energy.

Comment: So any solution?

Comment: I too, thought you were talking about a motorbike or motorcycle. For a bicycle with 18650 cells, IRFZ44N should be fine.

Comment: Will you be heating the entire handlebar, or only the grip area? Is it a metal handlebar? How will you prevent the heat loss from the entire handlebar?

Comment: Yes, it's metal and just grip area. Im not sure jet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length/diameter/resistance of the wire do not determine the temperature, but the power of the heater. The temperature depends on that power, but also how quickly the heat is removed from the handlebar. For example, with high windchill and rain, the heat will be removed much quicker than at low speeds in sunshine.

For that reason, you have to supply a generous amount of power to the heater and turn it off as soon the desired temperature is reached. This can be as simple as using a *bimetal thermal switch*. They cost a **ridiculous single dollar** and on a motorbike, they are generally more reliable than electronics.

Expect 10W per handle a good heater power for cruising. If you prefer to run your bike at 200km/h, better go with >20W.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Plan is to heat up (to selected temp) in 5 mins(max). I just hope heater won't suck more than 1A(limits of step-up converter). I don't ride when it rains, so it won't be a problem. Does exist some type of calculator for much heat I can get from eg. 2W in 10s?

Comment: You get 2W heat from a 2W heater. It's that simple. The temperature curve depends on the cooling. Without specifying that, you cannot calculate anything. That's why I gave those rules of thumb. Your time constant should be in the *seconds* range, not minutes. Imagine how dumb it would be if you're going from city traffic to the motorway and it needed five minutes to catch up with the higher windchill.

Comment: Also, why the heck you would need a *step-up converter*? Wire that heater directly to the 12V of the battery. And also, you don't need PWM or something like that. It's a heater. It cannot react faster than in the ~10s range. On-off by temperature regulation is sufficient. You need a closed loop regulation with temperature sensing anyways. Use a bimetal thermal switch.

Comment: I Know, it's stupid to talk in minutes but I'm limited with power supply(MT3604), since I use same supply(source for 12V) to power LEDs(in total around 0.5A).

Comment: You have a 12V battery on the motorbike, don't you?

Comment: I use 8x18650 LiIon batteries in paralel because charging - TP4056. Also Arduino and other el. comp. uses 5V so it's easier to boost voltage to 5V & 12V with step-ups

Comment: It's bicycle. I didn't say that, sorry.

Comment: You could wire your heater for the 3V of the lithium cells then. I don't see how this thing needs to run at 12V.

Comment: Btw does kanthal wire creates voltage drop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83655/discussion-between-janka-and-silviocro).